# Submodule of injective modules is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, injective-module

I was asked to prove that, given $A$ a ring, it is equivalent to say that "every submodule of a projective module is projective" and that "every submodule of an injective module is injective". However, that is not true for $A=\mathbb{Z}$, as the first statement holds ($\mathbb{Z}$ is hereditary) but not the second.

Is there some characterization for the rings that satisfy this second statement? That is, for which "every submodule of an injective module is injective.

Comment: “Every submodule of projective is projective” is equivalent to “every quotient of injective is injective”, which is equivalent to “hereditary”

Comment: Yes, I thought that this would be the correction needed

Answer (score 1):

Every module is a submodule of an injective module. So a ring with your property would have all its modules injective. That does exist: fields have this property. I'm not sure what the exact characterization is.

Comment: Humm that's true! Actually I know the characterization for this. A ring has all its modules injective if and only if it is semisimple.